# fetch array at the same way count specific results

Tags: sql, codeigniter

is there a possibility of fetch array while count the results 
i'm trying to create an attendance monitoring which count the no. of presents, absents, total no. of meetings per sched. ID and Student ID

here is my database

```
SCHED_ID |STUDENT_ID  |DATE       | A_STAT

1234567  |2014-000003 |08/01/14   |Absent

123456   |2014-000003 |08/04/2014 |Present

1234567  |2014-000003 |08/10/2014 |Present

123456   |2014-000003 |08/10/2014 |Present
```

the output supposed to be like this

Subject    Tot Num| Num of Days Present | Num of Days Absent
dasdasdasd  3            2                      1
testing123  3            2                      1
ASDASD      1            0                      1

but its always been like this

Subject    Tot Num |    Num of Days Present | Num of Days Absent

dasdasdasd  3                 1                   1

testing123  3                 1                   1

ASDASD      3                 1                   1

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (tbl_schedule c, tbl_subject d, tbl_attendance e) where  e.SCHED_ID = c.SCHED_ID AND d.SUBJECT_CODE = c.SUBJECT_CODE AND (e.STUDENT_ID = '$si') GROUP BY e.SCHED_ID")->result_array();

$query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (tbl_schedule c, tbl_subject d, tbl_attendance e) where  e.SCHED_ID = c.SCHED_ID AND d.SUBJECT_CODE = c.SUBJECT_CODE AND e.A_STAT='Present' AND (e.STUDENT_ID = '$si') GROUP BY e.SCHED_ID AND e.A_STAT")->num_rows();

$query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (tbl_schedule c, tbl_subject d, tbl_attendance e) where e.SCHED_ID = c.SCHED_ID AND d.SUBJECT_CODE = c.SUBJECT_CODE AND e.A_STAT='Absent' AND (e.STUDENT_ID = '$si') GROUP BY e.SCHED_ID AND e.A_STAT")->num_rows();

$query3 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (tbl_schedule c, tbl_subject d, tbl_attendance e) where e.SCHED_ID = c.SCHED_ID AND d.SUBJECT_CODE = c.SUBJECT_CODE AND (e.STUDENT_ID = '$si') GROUP BY e.SCHED_ID ")->num_rows();

```
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($query);$i++){
            $data[$i][0]=$query1; // present
            $data[$i][1]=$query2; //absent
            $data[$i][2]=$query3; //total
            $data[$i][3]=$query[$i]['SUBJECT _DESC']; // subj
        }


        return $data;
```

Comment: Do you have any code available? Have you attempted this yet?

Comment: i tried some and i ended up using 4 queries

and for loop